# Error: GCC could not be found - brew install git

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to get homebrew working on my osx 10.5.8 and after resolving all brew doctor's issues I'm trying to install git using brew:

```
    Mac-mini:~ Dagmara$ brew install git
    Error: GCC could not be found
    /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ENV.rb:142:in `gcc'
    /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ENV.rb:35:in `send'
    /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ENV.rb:35:in `setup_build_environment'
    /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:23
    /usr/local/Library/Formula/git.rb:86
    Error: Suspicious installation failure
```

This is a pain in the ass because if I run which gcc i get:

```
     /usr/bin/gcc
```

and while looking in /usr/bin I see 2 gcc installs:

```
    gcc      gcc-4.0
```

export $PATH:

```
    Mac-mini:~ Dagmara$ export $PATH
    -bash: export:`/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin/git:/usr/bin/gcc:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Not sure what's up with that valid idetifier issue though.
SO I need help fixing my GCC issue :)
Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Normally `gcc` is just a symbolic link - what do you get if you do `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc` ?

Comment: Also, why do you have `/usr/bin/gcc` in your `PATH` ? Please tell me that you don't have a directory in `/usr/bin` called `gcc` ?

Comment: @Paul R `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Jul 29 17:01 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.0`

Comment: @PaulR I removed `/usr/bin/gcc` from PATH. Now what?

Comment: What do you get for `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc-4.0` ?

Comment: @PaulR `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc-4.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  93072 Sep 24  2007 /usr/bin/gcc-4.0`

Comment: Looks OK - what happens if you type `gcc -v` at the command line ? Ditto for `g++ -v` ?

Comment: @PaulR for gcc -v: `comand not found` and for the second one:`
➜  ~  g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin9
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5465~16/src/configure --disable-checking -enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.0/ --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.0.0 --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin9 --with-arch=apple --with-tune=generic --host=i686-apple-darwin9 --target=i686-apple-darwin9
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)`

Comment: Very odd - I can only suggest that you re-install the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: Well, here's a problem: I have xcode 3.0 installed on my 10.6.8 and in preferences pannel I don't have the option of installing command line tools. How can I get them?

Comment: `export` takes a variable name without `$`.

Comment: Voted to close - this is specific to an old state of Homebrew and has been fixed.

Comment: I've had a similar problem and it resolved by itself after doing `brew update`. I've got Homebrew 0.9.5 now.